# How to create array from json in extjs for nested combobox

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, extjs, combobox

how to create array from json in extjs. Please find below json structure and the required array structure

```
 "DepartmantCodes": [
                    {
                        "DepartmentCode": "12",
                        "DivisionCode": [
                            "11",
                            "22"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "DepartmentCode": "22",
                        "DivisionCode": [
                            "21",
                            "23"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
Array structure 
    [
       ['12','11'],
       ['12','22'],
       ['22','21'],
       ['22','23'],


    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Ext.each` and an empty array you can iterate through the json object and create the required array:

```
        var endArray = [];
        Ext.each(departmentCodes,function(departmentCode){
            Ext.each(departmentCode.DivisionCode,function(divisionCode){
                endArray.push([departmentCode.DepartmentCode,divisionCode]);
            });
        });
```

I've double nested the foreach in the example because, although your code has only 2 division codes in each array, I assume there could be any number of division codes?

Here is a [fiddle for a working demonstration](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5um).